# sql excluding certain results

Tags: sql

lets say i have a data set of

```
A   B
--  --
a   1  
b   1  
c   1  
d   1  
d   2  
e   1  
f   1  
f   2  
g   1
```

how would i exclude a result in column B of 1, if column B has values of both 1 and 2 for the same value in column A?

i want my results to look like this

```
A   B  
--  --
a   1  
b   1  
c   1  
d   2  
e   1  
f   2  
g   1
```

Comment: Most likely you would use `EXISTS`.

Comment: are 1,2  fixed values? can we have 3?

Answer (score 0):

Checking explicitly here for the values 1 and 2 and using the fact that there are exactly two of them. You could potentially make this less cumbersome if it's safe to assume that you always want the highest value.

```
select
  tbl.A,
  tbl.B
from
  Table1 tbl
  left outer join (
    select
      A
    from
      Table1
    where
      B in (1,2)
    group by
      A
    having
      count(B) = 2
  ) mlt on tbl.A = mlt.A
where
  (
    mlt.A is not null 
    and tbl.B = 2
  ) or (
    mlt.A is null 
    and tbl.B = 1
  )
```

1. Figure out all the A values that have both 1 and 2.
2. Match those to the table on the A value.
3. If A is in the subquery, use the B = 2 record. If it isn't, use the B = 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

For the example data and desired result, the simplest query to achieve the result would be a `GROUP BY` operation and an aggregate function.

```
  SELECT d.A
       , MAX(d.B) AS B
    FROM my_data_set d
   GROUP BY d.A
   ORDER BY d.A
```

If we are only interested in rows that have a `1` or `2` in column `B`, we can add a `WHERE` clause

```
  SELECT d.A
       , MAX(d.B) AS B
    FROM my_data_set d
   WHERE d.B IN (1,2)
   GROUP BY d.A
   ORDER BY d.A
```

With the example data, the output is the same.

Both of these statements achieve the specified result. (There is only a *single* row returned for each distinct value in `A`.)

---

Or, for the same the example data, we can return the same result set with a more literal implementation of the specification.

To exclude rows with `1`when there is a row with `2` for the same value of `A`, we can use a `NOT EXISTS` predicate and a correlated subquery.

```
 SELECT d.A
      , d.B
   FROM my_data_set d
  WHERE ( d.B = 2 )
     OR ( d.B = 1 AND 
            NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                           FROM my_data_set e
                          WHERE e.A = d.A
                            AND e.B = 2
                       )
        )
  ORDER BY d.A, d.B
```

Comment: Wont work this the dataset below a,1
b,1
c,1
d,1
d,2
e,1
f,1
f,2
g,1
f,3

Comment: @sumit: As I said at the beginning of the answer, my suggestions were applicable to "*the example data and desired result*" given in the question. You are quite right to point out that given a different dataset, the return from the query would be different. (Actually, the second query in my answer would return the result specified in the answer given the dataset proposed in your comment.) It's not really specified in the question (it's ambiguous) what result should be returned when given a different dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
* from tbl where a IN 
(

select 

a from tbl 
group by a
having count(*)>1
)
and b!=1

UNION ALL

select 
* from tbl where a IN
 (

select 

a from tbl 
group by a
having count(*)=1
 )
```